# Consecutive log prints - only the first printed (no visible error)

Tags: java, log4j, error-logging

I have this code fragment in my java class:

```
catch (AuthenticationFailedException afe) {            
    IlientConf.logger.error("[" + accountID + "," + emailConf.getIncomingUser() + "@" + emailConf.getIncomingMailServer() + "] " + "E-Mail " + protocol + encStr + " login failed on " + emailConf.getIncomingUser() + "@" + emailConf.getIncomingMailServer());
    IlientConf.logger.error("[" + accountID + "," + emailConf.getIncomingUser() + "@" + emailConf.getIncomingMailServer() + "] " + afe.getMessage());
    IlientConf.logger.debug("Email integration AuthenticationFailedException", afe);
    return false;
}
```

IlientConf.logger is a log4j logger.

The actual log that is printed contains only the first line. This is it:

> [someuser,sapunlock@someuser.com@outlook.office365.com] E-Mail pop3
>   (SSL) login failed on sapunlock@someuser.com@outlook.office365.com

The second and the third log statements are lost somehow.
I really need the stack trace of the error, but I can't get it.
No other related error is shown in the log.

Please help me understand what the reason for this is.

P.S.: Of course I can change the log statements to show this better, but this is deployed at a customers environment and needs to be solved before the next version.

Comment: Could `afe.getMessage()` throw an `NPE`? Perhaps `afe` is `null`.

Comment: I don't think so, because the error is transferred to GUI and visible in a popup - 535 5.7.3 authentication unsuccessful...

Comment: The only difference between the first log entry and the second is the `afe.getMessage()`. If this action throws an exception that is not logged then what you observe would happen. So either `afe` is null or the `getMessage()` method threw an exception.